# Array out of bounds error android

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Hi I am new to andoid and keep getting the following error in my logcat but I can't find the problem in my java code. The app crashes after it goes round the array twice. I'm not sure where the array is out of bounds?

Logcat error:

```
05-04 14:46:22.947    3086-3086/com.example.Finished_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL   EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.Finished_app, PID: 3086
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
        at com.example.Finished_app.game1.onClick(game1.java:91)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Java code:

```
public class game1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    static Button next;
    static ImageView mainpic;
    static RadioGroup radioGroup;
    static RadioButton option1;
    static RadioButton option2;
    static RadioButton option3;
    static int[] mapPics = new int[]{R.drawable.america, R.drawable.england, R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.poland, R.drawable.sweden, R.drawable.spain};
    static String[] answers = new String[]{"Spain", "Poland", "Sweden", "America", "England", "Australia"};
    static int[] correctAnswer = new int[]{2, 1};
    static int score = 0;
    static int i = 0;
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 1;
    static int c = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game1);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        mainpic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mainpic.setImageResource(mapPics[i]);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        addListenerRadioGroup();
        option1.setText(String.valueOf(answers[a]));
        option2.setText(String.valueOf(answers[b]));
        option3.setText(String.valueOf(answers[c]));
    }//On Create

    public void addListenerRadioGroup() {
        option1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        option2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        option3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAnswers);
        radioGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSelectedAnswer();
        i++;
        a = a + 3;
        b = b + 3;
        c = c + 3;
        if (i >= 1) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, scores.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("scores", score);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }//if
        mainpic.setImageResource(mapPics[i]);
        option1.setText(String.valueOf(answers[a]));
        option2.setText(String.valueOf(answers[b]));
        option3.setText(String.valueOf(answers[c]));
        mapPics[i] = null;
    }//onClick

    public void getSelectedAnswer() {
        int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
        if (index == correctAnswer[i])
            score++;
    }//get selected answer

}//class
```

Answer (score 2):

`length=6; index=6`

Arrays are 0 based.
If your array has 6 elements, the range is 0, ..., 5

**[EDIT]**

In your onClick, the value of i increases too much.
It arrives to a value (6) which exceeds the array length.

You should add a condition to verify if i > 5 then reset it to 0.
Or add a similar logic (I'm not entering the logic of your game).

Just to make sure that i is inside the range 0, ..., 5.